# Как одновременно запустить 2 метода?

Tags: python-3.x

Есть 2 метода:

```
    def input_event(self):
    for event in self.long_poll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if len(event.object.attachments) >= 1:
                user_id = event.object.from_id
                username = self.get_user_name(user_id)
                text = event.object.text
                data = {'user_id': user_id, 'username': username, 'text': text}
                input_events.append(data)
                # print(input_events)

    def read_input(self):
    while True:
        for position in range(len(input_events)):
            print(input_events[position])
            print(input_events)
            if input_events[position].get('text') == 'привет':
                buffer_events = input_events[position]
                print(buffer_events)
                input_events.remove(position)
                print(input_events)
```

Первый прослушивает поток и сохраняет нужные мне данные словарем в список, второй должен искать нужные мне данные в списке.
Не понимаю как мне запустить одновременно эти 2 метода? Пробовал создавать отдельный файл, в котором произвожу вызов этих методов - не работает. Пробовал для каждого метода создать отдельный файл с вызовом и запускать их - тоже не работает.

UPD.
Нашел такой способ:

```
def main_start(self):
    Thread(target=self.input_event()).start()
    Thread(target=self.read_input()).start()
```

Первый метод как и раньше работает и запускается, второй - никакой реакции. Пробовал даже простой вывод делать print('some text') - ничего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в параметр `target` нужно передавать ссылку на метод, а не результат его вызова.

```
Thread(target=self.input_event).start()
Thread(target=self.read_input).start()
```

Comment: Приложение стартует и сразу-же закрывает без каких либо ошибок: Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: А нет, все работает, спасибо.